# Ubuntu 18.04 Wifi slow on HP Laptop with Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 & Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

Here's my setup:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   logical name: wlo1
   version: c4
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz

   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 07
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
```

Wifi barely connects and when it does is extremely slow (< 1mbps).

Tried using various iwlwifi.conf settings, but none seem to work.

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

From: [Ubuntu Forums - Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 connection is very slow](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246457)

Success was found using:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Of course since you've alread setup the `iwlwifi` option you can simply change the `0` to an `8`.

Apparently `0` was old school and `8` is for newer drivers (sometime before September 2014 when OP posted question).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to switch your wireless mode from 802.11bgn to, 802.11bg directly from your router WiFI settings. Unfortunately, this will just solve the issue when connecting particularly on that router.